# How to navigate between screens without adding it to tabNavigation in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Suppose you have a react native app that has a flow that navigates between screens upon data entry, how would you navigate through these screens without having to add these screens to a `stackNavigation` or `createbottomtabnavigator`?

For example here is my app upon being on home page.

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

3) It gets added to navigation tab menu  :(

[image]

here is the navigation code.

```
import React from "react";
// import HomeView from "./components/screens/Home";
import AddPostView from "./containers/addPost";
import SettingsView from "./containers/settings";
import ContentView from "./components/screens/AddContent";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import DashboardView from "./components/screens/Dashboard";
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs";

const AppNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: AddPostView, // shows the title screen is there a way i can nest the screens apart of this screen ?
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="home" color={tintColor} size={24} />
        )
      }
    },
    Content: {
      screen: ContentView, // shows add content screen. 
      labeled: false,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: false,
        tabBarLabel: false
      }
    },
    Dashboard: {
      screen: DashboardView,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="dashboard" color={tintColor} size={24} />
        )
      }
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: SettingsView,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="user" color={tintColor} size={24} />
        )
      }
    }
  },

  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    activeColor: "#f0edf6",
    tabBarLabel: "Content",
    inactiveColor: "#333333",
    barStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#B9D2B1",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center"
    }
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

**AddPost.jsx**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Subheading, Dialog } from "react-native-paper";
import PostForm from "../forms/createPost/createPost";
export default class AddPostView extends Component {
  state = {
    title: "",
    content: "",
    touched: {
      title: false,
      content: false
    }
  };
  titleChange = title => {
    this.setState({ title });
  };
  validate = field => {
    console.log("tet", field);
    this.setState({
      touched: { ...this.state.touched, [field]: true }
    });
    console.log(this.state.touched);
  };
  contentChange = content => {
    this.setState({ content });
  };

  render() {
    const isEnabled = this.state.title.length > 6 ? false : true;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Subheading style={styles.labels}> Add An Entry</Subheading>
        <PostForm
          title={this.state.title}
          titleChange={this.titleChange}
          disButton={isEnabled}
          hasError={this.state.touched}
          onSubmit={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Content")}
          validateTitle={() => this.validate("title")}
        />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  labels: {
    textAlign: "center",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 25,
    padding: 20,
    marginTop: 50
  }
});
```

Comment: if you don't want to use Navigation then you can try Carasoul . https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel . I am also use it for pagination

Comment: This seems like more of a design than an functionality. Thank you for sharing but this is not the approach i would liked to use :( .

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this. Here were my steps

1) Create a new file called **otherNav.jsx** (this can handle multiple screens for different scenarios, for now i just need it to navigation to a form)

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import ContentView from "./containers/addContent";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign";

const OtherNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Content: {
      screen: ContentView
    }
  },
  {
    headerMode: "none",
    activeColor: "#f0edf6",
    tabBarLabel: "Content",
    inactiveColor: "#333333",
    barStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#B9D2B1",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center"
    }
  }
);
export default createAppContainer(OtherNavigation);
```

2) Call this in AuthNav where all the navigations live

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import AuthLoadingScreen from "./AuthLoadingScreen";
import AuthNavigation from "./splashNav";
import AppNavigator from "./loggedInNav";
import OtherNavigation from "./otherNav";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
export default createAppContainer(
  createStackNavigator(
    {
      AuthLoading: {
        screen: AuthLoadingScreen // intimidiary between App && Auth checks for token and such
      },
      App: AppNavigator,
      Content: OtherNavigation,
      Auth: AuthNavigation 
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "AuthLoading",
      headerMode: "none"
    }
  )
);
```

3) Now this will flow accordingly

```
  render() {
    const isEnabled = this.state.title.length > 6 ? false : true;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Subheading style={styles.labels}> Add An Entry</Subheading>
        <PostForm
          title={this.state.title}
          titleChange={this.titleChange}
          disButton={isEnabled}
          hasError={this.state.touched}
          onSubmit={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Content")}
          validateTitle={() => this.validate("title")}
        />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

So now we have this (end result its not added to bottomNav)

1)

[image]

2) [image]